# Using replace while exporting table contents from SQL database table using powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv

I'm exporting the contents of a SQL table to a `.csv` file, and during the process, I need to check one of the columns for an email address that doesn't contain the words "hotmail", and if it doesn't, I want to replace the email address with an empty string.

Below is what I have. If it's easier I could update the downloaded file after it's completed but can't seem to get either to work.

```
param
(
[String] $destination = 'C:\Temp\',
[String] $ServerName = '10.42.00.000,000',
[String] $dbname = 'Test',
[String] $TableName = 'Test_Data'
)
invoke-sqlcmd -query "SELECT 
Employee_Code,
Employee_Name,
Legal_Firstname,
Legal_Middle_Name,

    if ($_.'Work_Email' -notin @('%hotmail')) {
        $_ | Add-Member -Name '' -type NoteProperty -Value $lineno
        $_ # Output to pipeline
    },
Hire_Date
FROM $TableName" -database $dbname -serverinstance $ServerName |export-csv -path   $destination$TableName.csv
```

Comment: That looks like it's going to generate invalid syntax.
Why would you not just use a case expression? `CASE WHEN Work_Email LIKE '%Hotmail%' THEN '' ELSE Work_Email END AS Work_Email`

Comment: I had tried that originally and must have had a typo of some sort.  I just tried it again and it worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Either perform the replace operatoin in the SQL query:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query @"
SELECT 
Employee_Code,
Employee_Name,
Legal_Firstname,
Legal_Middle_Name,
CASE 
  WHEN Work_Email NOT LIKE '%hotmail%'
  THEN ''
  ELSE Work_Email
END AS 'Work_Email',
Hire_Date
FROM $TableName
"@ ...
```

If, on the other hand, you want to perform the replace operation client-side, you can either use a wildcard string comparison with the `-like` operator, and use `*` in place of `%`:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd ... |ForEach-Object {
    # conditionally replace the property value...
    if ($_.Work_Email -notlike '*hotmail*') {
        $_.Work_Email = ''
    }

    # ... and then output the modified object
    $_
} |Export-Csv ...
```